# How do I delete flash cookies in a selenium script?

Tags: flash, selenium, session-cookies

I'm running a selenium script that tests an authenticated application.

The application uses a flash cookie to know if a user is authenticated to the site.
   Mid-script I need to delete the flash cookie.    Any ideas?

I've tried to script the flash player settings page http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html with no luck.

We use PHPUnit/Selenium if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried selenium.deleteAllVisibleCookies()?

Comment: I have.  Unfortunately it only removes browser cookies.   Flash, being a desktop app, keeps its cookies separate.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to delete flash cookies using Selenium since Flash cookies are stored in a separate location and as such using the selenium.deleteAllVisibleCookies() command will not work. Depending on which operating system you testing on, you can write a script that deletes all flash cookies before beginning the Selenium test run. So if you are running on OSX for example, you can write a script to delete LSO files in

~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash\ Player

Comment: Hrm.  Interesting idea.   I'll toy with this and see what happens.